# Angular route guards doesn't work as expected when returning Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

So i have this code:

Basically this guard listens for the occurence of certain success and failure ngrx actions and i map it to their boolean equivalents. But for some reason this doesn't work as expected.

Doesn't `ofType` rxjs operator gets executed once a target action gets dispatched w/c i believe should work in the code below. I use `mapTo` operator to map success action to boolean true and false to failure action.

**bookmark-must-exist.guard.ts**

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {
      CanActivate,
      ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      RouterStateSnapshot,
      Router,
    } from '@angular/router';
    import { Observable, merge, race, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
    import { Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
    import { take, mapTo, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
    import * as bookmarkActions from '@app/features/bookmarks/state/actions/bookmarks.actions';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class BookmarkMustExistGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(
        private store: Store,
        private actions$: Actions,
        private router: Router
      ) {}
    
      canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
      ): Observable<boolean> {
        const bookmarkId = route.params.id;
        this.store.dispatch(
          bookmarkActions.selectOrLoadBookmark({ id: bookmarkId })
        );
    
        const successAction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(
            bookmarkActions.selectBookmarkInStoreSuccess
            bookmarkActions.loadBookmarkFromApiSuccess
          ),
          mapTo(true),
          take(1)
        );
    
        const failureAction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(bookmarkActions.loadBookmarksFailure),
          mapTo(false),
          take(1)
        );
        return race(successAction$, failureAction$).pipe(
          tap(value => {
            if (!value) {
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/not-found');
            }
          }),
          take(1)
        );
      }
    }
```

It seems like the observables from `ofType` inside the guard doesn't complete even if i add a `take(1)` operator

Btw, this is the routing module for the **lazy-loaded** module

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { BookmarkMustExistGuard } from './guards/bookmark-must-exist.guard';
import { BookmarksPageComponent } from './containers/bookmarks-page/bookmarks-page.component';
import { BookmarksCurrentListContainerComponent } from './containers/bookmarks-current-list-container-container/bookmarks-current-list-container.component';
import { BookmarkSearchResultsContainerComponent } from './containers/bookmark-search-results-container/bookmark-search-results-container.component';
import { BookmarkArchivesContainerComponent } from './containers/bookmark-archives-container/bookmark-archives-container.component';
import { BookmarkFavoritesContainerComponent } from './containers/bookmark-favorites-container/bookmark-favorites-container.component';
import { BookmarksByTagContainerComponent } from './containers/bookmarks-by-tag-container/bookmarks-by-tag-container.component';
import { BookmarkReaderViewPageComponent } from './containers/bookmark-reader-view-page/bookmark-reader-view-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BookmarksPageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: BookmarksCurrentListContainerComponent,
        data: {
          reuseRoute: true,
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        component: BookmarkSearchResultsContainerComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'archives',
        component: BookmarkArchivesContainerComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'favorites',
        component: BookmarkFavoritesContainerComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'tags/:name',
        component: BookmarksByTagContainerComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'reader/:id',
    component: BookmarkReaderViewPageComponent,
    canActivate: [BookmarkMustExistGuard],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class BookmarksRoutingModule {}
```

here's the relevant effect

```js
  selectOrLoadBookmark$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(bookmarkActions.selectOrLoadBookmark),
      switchMap(({ id }) => {
        return of(id).pipe(
          withLatestFrom(
            this.store.select(bookmarksSelectors.selectCurrentBookmark(id))
          )
        );
      }),
      switchMap(([id, bookmarkInStore]) => {
        console.log({ id, bookmarkInStore });
        const bookmarkFromApi$ = this.bookmarksService.getBookmark(id).pipe(
          map(({ bookmark }) => {
            return bookmarkActions.loadBookmarkFromApiSuccess({
              bookmark,
            });
          }),
          catchError(error =>
            of(
              bookmarkActions.loadBookmarkFromApiFailure({
                error: error?.error?.message,
              })
            )
          )
        );

        const bookmarkFromStore = bookmarkActions.selectBookmarkInStoreSuccess({
          bookmark: bookmarkInStore,
        });

        // if (!!bookmarkInStore) {
        // return of(bookmarkFromStore);
        // }
        // return bookmarkFromApi$;

        return iif(
          () => !!bookmarkInStore,
          of(bookmarkFromStore),
          bookmarkFromApi$
        );
      })
    );
  });
```

Comment: Perhaps the guard should tap into the ngrx store for success/failure information instead of looking for actions dispatched from the effect? Step 1: Effect dispatches success/failure action with data. Step 2: Reducer updates the store with that info. Step 3: Guard is subscribed to that slice of info.

Comment: @Abhishek thanks. i was able to solve it. Check my answer if there's something that isn't right or something that can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

after hours of debugging, i was finally able to find something that works.

#### Problem:

So basically, the possible problems with my previous implementation are

1. from my Effects code.
   It basically returns a **synchronous** `of(bookmarkFromStore)` observable (the scheduler defaults to `queueScheduler` for the `of` operator w/c i believe is synchronous) or `bookmarkFromApi$` w/c is asynchronous one resulting from a http call.

   ```js
    return iif(
          () => !!bookmarkInStore,
          of(bookmarkFromStore),
          bookmarkFromApi$
        );
   ```
2. based on the above point, the dispatched actions intercepted thru `ofType` have probably emitted before the route guard is able to subscribe(using `race` operator) to those actions. Due to the fact that one of the possible actions dispatched is a synchronous one ( `of(bookmarkFromStore)`), the following lines will most likely miss the emitted value

   ````js
        // the effect will intercept this action w/c may result in a synchronous observable, w/c the `race` operator will probably miss
        this.store.dispatch(
          bookmarkActions.selectOrLoadBookmark({ id: bookmarkId })
        );

        const successAction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(
            bookmarkActions.selectBookmarkInStoreSuccess
            bookmarkActions.loadBookmarkFromApiSuccess
          ),
          mapTo(true),
          take(1)
        );
        ```
   ````

---

#### Solution:

Basically what i came up with is to query the store using **selectors**. During the success actions, i set a `loaded` flag to indicate a success action.

Under the `canActivate` method in the code below, check the `isFound$` and `error$` observable w/c are mapped to true and false respectively.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, merge, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import {
  take,
  mapTo,
  tap,
  withLatestFrom,
  switchMap,
  filter,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

import * as bookmarkActions from '@app/features/bookmarks/state/actions/bookmarks.actions';
import * as bookmarksSelectors from '@app/features/bookmarks/state/selectors/bookmarks.selectors';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BookmarkMustExistGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private store: Store,
    private actions$: Actions,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  isFound(id: string) {
    const isLoaded$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(bookmarksSelectors.selectBookmarksLoaded),
      filter(loaded => !!loaded)
    );

    return isLoaded$.pipe(
      switchMap(loaded => {
        return of(loaded).pipe(
          tap(loadedValue => console.log({ loadedValue })),
          withLatestFrom(
            this.store.pipe(
              select(bookmarksSelectors.selectCurrentBookmark(id))
            ),
            (_, currentBookmark) => currentBookmark
          ),
          tap(currentBookmark => console.log({ currentBookmark }))
        );
      })
    );
  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    const bookmarkId = route.params.id;

    this.store.dispatch(
      bookmarkActions.selectOrLoadBookmark({ id: bookmarkId })
    );

    const isFound$ = this.isFound(bookmarkId).pipe(mapTo(true));
    const error$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(bookmarksSelectors.selectBookmarksError),
      mapTo(false)
    );

    return merge(isFound$, error$).pipe(
      tap(value => {
        if (!value) {
          this.router.navigate(['/not-found']);
        }
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  }
}
```